# Capture HTTP Referer in network traffic for whatsapp using Developer tools in Firefox

Tags: firefox, network-traffic

I'm using the Network traffic capture feature in developer tools in Firefox to see the network traffic generated when clicking on a link in a chat message on web version of whatsapp.

However, when I click on the link, it opens in a new tab on the browser but I can't see the HTTP referer field in this case. How can I leverage developer's tools network monitoring feature in Firefox to check this?

Thanks.